# how to fire 400 requests per second in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a system with 8GB ram, with Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3450 CPU @ 3.10GHz CPU, I tried JMeter with 400 requests with a ramp-up period of 1 second, but it sending only 166 requests per second, currently assigned heap memory to JMeter is 2048 Mb.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You will send exact 400 requests per second with 300 threads only if response time will be 0.75 second. If it will be more - you will have less requests.

The options are in:

1. Increase number of threads to be enough to maintain 400 requests per second concurrency. The main factor is your application response time, if it will be 1 second - go for 400 threads for 1 request, if it is 2 seconds - you will need 800 threads for 1 request, etc. You can try setting the number of threads to i.e. 1000 and slowing the requests down using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
2. The same as point 1, but assumes a different timer - [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - more "advanced" version of the Constant Throughput Timer which is more precise and there you can have more complex concurrency patterns

Comment: sorry, I did mistakenly written 300

Comment: Constant Throughput Timer allows throughput per minutes, I want per seconds

Comment: Prepare for a piece of eternal wisdom: there are 60 seconds in minute. So 400 requests per second == 24000 requests per minute and 300 requests per second == 18000 requests per minute.

Comment: But if it is not able to send more than 166 requests per seconds then how can we be sure that it will work with Constant Throughput Timer?

Comment: **Set number of threads in Thread Group to something very high, i.e. 1000** and use the Constant Throughput Timer to limit the throughput to desired rate in requests per second/minute.